# What are the differences between MSMQ and WF?

Tags: .net, workflow, msmq, workflow-foundation

When should I use Message Queuing (MSMQ) or Workflow Fundation (WF)? What exaclty are these two products? How could you define them? What are their properties? What are their utilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MSMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) is a message queue implementation, sometimes also used as a form of interprocess communication.

[Windows Workflow Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation) is an API over a workflow engine.

Although you could implement (part of) a workflow engine using MSMQ, the two technologies have very little relation to each other really. Consider using MSMQ if you need a message queue implementation, for details on how it works see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Consider using WF if you need a workflow engine.  For details, again see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328)

Comment: Yes but the message queue implementation is a type of workflow, no?

Comment: @DranDane Not really - workflow is typically *far* more complex than a simple queue.

Comment: @DranDane maybe if you re-worded your question to explain exactly what programming challenge you are facing you would get more meaningful help. Your question does not entirely make sense.

Comment: @DranDane: a process/workflow/saga may entail multiple messages that may be transported over msmq (or any queuing technology) but msmq and WF are totally different animals.